# Two Arrays in Function i want to pass out of the function to local variables - PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, function, variables

I have the following code:

```
$lines;
$invalidNumber = [];
$validNumber = [];

    function readCSV($thefile) {
        $i = 0;
        $file = fopen($thefile, 'r');

        // Put numbers from CSV into array
        while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
            // Write lines to array
            $lines[$i] = $line;
            $i++;
        }

        fclose($file);

        validateNumbers($lines);
    }


    // Go through array sorting numbers into invalidNumber and validnumbers 
    function validateNumbers($lines) {
    // Valid numbers togo to reuqests and invalid to csvFile to be displayed seperately
        $validNumber = [];
        $invalidNumber = [];

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($lines); ++$i) {
            echo "</br>";
            $number[$i] = $lines[$i][0];
            echo $number[$i] . "  length: " . strlen($number[$i]);

            /*
            switch on length of number: , , 

            */
            switch (strlen($number[$i])) {
                case 10:
                    if (substr($number[$i], 0, -9) != 7) {
                        $inc = count($invalidNumber);
                        $invalidNumber[$inc++] = $number[$i];
                    } else {
                        $vnc = count($validNumber);
                        $validNumber[$vnc++] = $number[$i];
                    }
                    break;
                case 11:
                        switch (substr($number[$i], 0, -9)) {
                            case 07:
                            $vnc = count($validNumber);
                            $validNumber[$vnc++] = $number[$i];
                            break;
                            default:
                            $inc = count($invalidNumber);
                            $invalidNumber[$inc++] = $number[$i];
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 12:
                    switch (substr($number[$i], 0, -9)) {
                        case 447:
                        $vnc = count($validNumber);
                        $validNumber[$vnc++] = $number[$i];
                        break;
                        case '077':
                        $vnc = count($validNumber);
                        $validNumber[$vnc++] = $number[$i];
                        break;
                        default:
                        $inc = count($invalidNumber);
                        $invalidNumber[$inc++] = $number[$i];
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 13:
                    switch (substr($number[$i], 0, -9)) {
                            case '+447':
                            $vnc = count($validNumber);
                            $validNumber[$vnc++] = $number[$i];
                            break;
                            default:
                            $inc = count($invalidNumber);
                            $invalidNumber[$inc++] = $number[$i];
                            break;
                        }
                    break;
                default:
                    // if number is not 10, 11, 12 or 13 charaters long if < 10 (SKIP), if = 10 & charAt 1 != 7 (invalid)
                    echo "Invalid Number";
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to pass the arrays $validNumber and $invalidNumber out of the function to the arrays I declare at the top of the page, I cannot seem to do it no matter how I try.

Comment: just use a `return` value of an array for invalid and valid

Comment: You need to look at [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) But **please** avoid using `global`

Comment: You can use reference parameters for the functions and hand in the array that should be modified by the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First pass the arrays to the function as parameter, making them IN-SCOPE

Now if you also use the `&` reference operator then you are passing a reference to the original array and not a copy of that array to both these functions. So whatever you do to them will be done to the array itself and not a copy of the array.

```
function readCSV($thefile, &$invalidNumber, &$validNumber, &$lines) {
    $i = 0;
    $file = fopen($thefile, 'r');

    // Put numbers from CSV into array
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
        // Write lines to array
        $lines[$i] = $line;
        $i++;
    }

    fclose($file);

    validateNumbers(&$lines, $invalidNumber, $validNumber);
}


// Go through array sorting numbers into invalidNumber and validnumbers 
function validateNumbers($lines, &$invalidNumber, &$validNumber, &$lines) {
    // Valid numbers togo to reuqests and 
    // invalid to csvFile to be displayed seperately


    for ($i = 0; $i < count($lines); ++$i) {
        echo "</br>";
        $number[$i] = $lines[$i][0];
        echo $number[$i] . "  length: " . strlen($number[$i]);

        /*
        switch on length of number: , , 

        */
        switch (strlen($number[$i])) {
            case 10:
                if (substr($number[$i], 0, -9) != 7) {
                    $inc = count($invalidNumber);
                    $invalidNumber[$inc++] = $number[$i];
                } else {
                    $vnc = count($validNumber);
                    $validNumber[$vnc++] = $number[$i];
                }
                break;
            case 11:
                    switch (substr($number[$i], 0, -9)) {
                    case 07:
                        $vnc = count($validNumber);
                        $validNumber[$vnc++] = $number[$i];
                        break;
                    default:
                        $inc = count($invalidNumber);
                        $invalidNumber[$inc++] = $number[$i];
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 12:
                switch (substr($number[$i], 0, -9)) {
                    case 447:
                        $vnc = count($validNumber);
                        $validNumber[$vnc++] = $number[$i];
                        break;
                    case '077':
                        $vnc = count($validNumber);
                        $validNumber[$vnc++] = $number[$i];
                        break;
                    default:
                        $inc = count($invalidNumber);
                        $invalidNumber[$inc++] = $number[$i];
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 13:
                switch (substr($number[$i], 0, -9)) {
                case '+447':
                    $vnc = count($validNumber);
                    $validNumber[$vnc++] = $number[$i];
                    break;
                default:
                    $inc = count($invalidNumber);
                    $invalidNumber[$inc++] = $number[$i];
                    break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                // if number is not 10, 11, 12 or 13 charaters long if < 10 (SKIP), if = 10 & charAt 1 != 7 (invalid)
                echo "Invalid Number";
                break;

        }
    }
}

$lines = [];
$invalidNumber = [];
$validNumber = [];

readCSV('the_file_name', $invalidNumber, $validNumber, $lines);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention the validateNumber($lines) is called from upload.php and passes the file location in and doesn't know the contents to append them to the calling of the function.

Comment: Well then you have to amend the `'the_file_name'` to whatever you use

Comment: I think I get what you mean can I call validateNumber($lines) from the upload.php page and then the &$ on the &$invalidNumber and &$validNumber come from variables in the ProccessArray.php page

Comment: You made no mention of `upload.php` in your question so I am kinda lost

Comment: I confussed myself the validateNumbers is called inside the readCSV function, I have to pass the variable out of the validateNumbers function to the page so the other page I have can view them. I think I have to try to make it more Object Orientated.

Comment: Looking back at this Question/Answer I thought I should add how I ended up getting the numbers separated. First off I will say thanks to rig's for making me realise its a simple task and the original code had just iterated over every number calling functions and it was messy. I ended up as i said making it more object orientated and just passing all of the numbers over in a file handler and then verified a list into numbers dropping any number which hadn't met a criteria... much simpler, Cheers Rig's.